# How to convert the date format from angular-material

Tags: angular-material

How to convert this type of data from angular material datepicker

```
dateFrom: '2018-10-03T16:00:00.000Z'
```

to this type of data, generated by Date.now ?

```
dateFrom : '2018-10-10 14:50:16.479'
```

then I will use the data in my query

Answer (score 0):

Use moment

```js
console.log(moment('2018-10-03T16:00:00.000Z').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a good cheat sheet

https://devhints.io/moment